# Listen to disconnections of tcp clients in Google Chrome app

Tags: sockets, google-chrome-app

In the documentation for [chrome.sockets.tcpServer](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcpServer) and [chrome.sockets.tcp](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp) there is nowhere mentioned how to listen to disconnection of clients. How can I do it?

I found out that you get a `resultCode == -15` in the callback of the `chrome.sockets.tcp.send`-function if the client was disconnected. But I really want to get notified if someone disconnects instead of use only the pro-active method of checking that.

Comment: Wouldn't `chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError` be dispatched?

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that socket disconnection isn't something the underlying OS can detect. There's no socket-level way to tell the difference between a client that is gone and a client that might simply be taking a while to send the next packet. It's possible someone with deeper TCP/IP knowledge will correct me, but this is always the answer I've seen.

You can have clients send an application-level disconnect message, or else a periodic heartbeat without which the server will conclude the client is gone. More detail here: [Is TCP Keepalive the only mechanism to determine a broken link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348658/is-tcp-keepalive-the-only-mechanism-to-determine-a-broken-link/348799#348799)

Comment: Yeah, I think I might expressed myself not well enough. I know indeed that there's no real event, but for example calling ``recv`` in Winsock returns zero when the connection is gracefully disconnected. But in Chrome sockets API, I cannot call any ``recv`` function since there's only a listener and therefor cannot check whether the connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I thought chrome.sockets gave you an onReceived event with byteLength 0 packet which means they disconnect, right? I mean that's how I would gracefully disconnect, send a payload with 0 bytes.

Comment: Poorly, that's not the case.